# install Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330

Tags: drivers

I am new on ubuntu and i use xubuntu 16.04
my graphic card is AMD and Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330
how i can install this driver ?

Comment: If you have video you have a graphics card working. You don't need to install anything else and you can't because there are no AMD proprietary drivers for 16.04. You're running the default open-source *radeon* and that should be fine for your hardware.